# Dice game pig in C++

Tags: c++, dice

First time poster here, so bear with me. I'm also really new at C++. I am coding this game based on the dice game called Pig. It's close to working right, but I'm having some problems. The point of the game is to reach 100 points but I'm not sure how to code this. I've tried several ways, like while loops or if statements, but none of them have worked. I want it to say who wins as soon as the winning die is rolled. What would be the best way to do this?

I was also having problems with it looping correctly. It's supposed to go back to the player's loop after the computer passes, but it wants to just exit. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int die;
    int myScore = 95;
    int devilScore = 95; 
    int turnScore = 0;
    int myScoretotal = myScore += turnScore; 
    int devilScoretotal = devilScore += turnScore;
    char choice; 
    bool change = false; 


    cout << "Welcome to Devil's Dice! Please select from the following menu: ";         

    while(change == false){ //&& devilScoretotal < 100 && myScoretotal < 100){ 
        cout << "\nRoll [r], Pass [p], or Quit [q].";
        cin >> choice; 

        if(choice == 'r'){
            die=(rand() % 6 + 1); //Number generator for die

            if(die > 1){
                cout << "You rolled a " << die << "." << endl; 
                turnScore += die; 
                cout << "You will add " << turnScore << " points if you pass now. ";}
            else{
                cout << "You rolled a 1. You lose your points and your turn ends." << endl; 
                change = true; 
                turnScore = 0; 
            }
        }  

        if(choice == 'p') 
        {myScore += turnScore; 
            cout << "Your score is now " << myScore << "." << endl;
            turnScore = 0; 
            change = true; }  //needs to go to Devil now


        if(choice == 'q')
        {cout << "\n\tThanks for playing! "; 
            return 0; }

        else if(choice > 'r' || choice < 'p')
        {cout << "Please select from the choices listed."; }

    }

    while(change == true){// && devilScoretotal < 100 && myScoretotal < 100){ //The Devil's actions

        if(myScore > devilScore && turnScore < 17 || devilScore > myScore && turnScore < 12 || devilScore > 84){

            choice='r'; 
            cout << "The Devil rolls! " << endl;                    

            if(choice == 'r'){
                die=(rand() % 6 + 1); //Number generator for die 
                if(die > 1){

                    cout << "The Devil rolls a " << die << "." << endl; 
                    turnScore += die; 
                }else{
                    cout << "The Devil rolls a 1. He loses his points and now it's your turn!" << endl;  
                    turnScore = 0; 
                    change = false; 
                }          

            }else{

                cout << "The Devil chooses to pass. "; 
                devilScore += turnScore; 
                choice='p'; 
                turnScore = 0; 
                cout << "He has " << devilScore << " points. " << endl;
                cout << "The Devil now has " << devilScore << " points." << endl; 
                change = false; 
            }                              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Andrea, welcome to SO.  Your question is asking for a lot of advice, and people probably won't want to give much.  We work best when there's one clear question that can have one clear answer, and it's important to help people learn for themselves, so that we're not just feeding answers.  Here are some tips, looking at your code, maybe you can update your code from that point.  1) Why is it exiting after the devil rolls?  You have one loop to give the player a turn, and one for the devil.  You need an outer loop that goes effectively forever - and then you return if the user quits or wins.

Comment: 2) The easiest thing you can do to determine winning is put the entire die roll inside a function.  Functions are good for removing duplicate code, and rolling a die and checking a score all fit well for that.  You could make functions that handle rolling the die and ones for adding the score.  Inside the function that adds to the score, you can check to see if the score is 100, and if so, give a win message and exit.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The looping problem in your code seems to occur because the entirety of the code doesn't loop, resulting in only one iteration of the game to occur. you should put the code from the player's turn to the end of the devil's turn into a loop with a condition something like this

> while(hasSomeoneWonYet==false){ code }

this will keep the turns alternating until has someoneWonYet is true

As to how to check win conditions, the way I would do it is to put a statement checking if win conditions have been met at the end of each player's turn. something like the following:

> if (winConditionsMet){ hasSomeoneWonYet=true;}

replace win conditions met with the actual conditions and it should work better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code to help you out:

```
turn = player
winner = false
rolled_1 = false
pass = false

while !winner

    if turn == player

        show the player options (roll, pass, or quit)

        respond to player's choice

    else if turn == computer
        logic for what computer does for its roll

        respond to computer's choice

    check for winner

    if winner
        announce winner
    else
        if rolled 1 or pass was chosen
            if turn == computer
                turn = player
            else
                turn = computer

(winner became true, so the while loop is exited, and the program finishes)
```

Use the indentation to know where to put the curly brackets.  A lot of IDE's have a "format" or "indentation" helper of some sort.

Also because turn is only two values, you could change it to a boolean, such as `is_computer_turn`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: You have two loops controlling each player's turn, but they are not enclosed in an outer loop that will repeat the turns until a condition is met (the winning condition).

Problem 2: You should check the winning condition when the rolled number + turn score + total score is >= 100. In this case you can simply print the winning statement and return.

A possible solution is (I'm using infinite loops and breaks, not very elegant but it should do) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int die;
  int myScore = 0;
  int devilScore = 0;
  int turnScore = 0;
  char choice;
  bool change = false;

  bool weHaveAWinner = false;
  cout << "Welcome to Devil's Dice! Please select from the following menu: ";

    //Enclosing infinite loop, only can exit on return
    while (true) {
    //Player turn loop, can exit with breaks to main loop
    while (true){
      cout << "\nRoll [r], Pass [p], or Quit [q].";
      cin >> choice;

      if(choice == 'r'){
        die=(rand() % 6 + 1); //Number generator for die

        if(die > 1){
          cout << "You rolled a " << die << "." << endl;
          turnScore += die;
          if (turnScore + myScore >=100) {
            cout << "You win!" << endl;
            //Winning condition met. Game over and return.
            return 0;
          }
          cout << "You will add " << turnScore << " points if you pass now. ";}
        else{
          cout << "You rolled a 1. You lose your points and your turn ends." << endl;
          turnScore = 0;
          //End turn. Breaks secondary loop.
          break;
        }
      }

      if(choice == 'p')   {
        myScore += turnScore;
        cout << "Your score is now " << myScore << "." << endl;
        turnScore = 0;
        change = true;
        //End turn. Breaks secondary loop.
        break;
      }  //needs to go to Devil now


      if(choice == 'q')
      {cout << "\n\tThanks for playing! ";
        return 0; }

      else if(choice > 'r' || choice < 'p')
      {cout << "Please select from the choices listed."; }

    }

    while (true){
       //Devil's turn loop, can exit with breaks to main loop
      if(myScore > devilScore && turnScore < 17 || devilScore > myScore && turnScore < 12 || devilScore > 84){

        choice='r';
        cout << "The Devil rolls! " << endl;

        if(choice == 'r'){
          die=(rand() % 6 + 1); //Number generator for die
          if(die > 1){
            cout << "The Devil rolls a " << die << "." << endl;
            turnScore += die;
            if (turnScore + devilScore >=100) {
              //Winning condition met. Game over and return.
              cout << "The Devil wins!" << endl;
              return 0;
            }
          }else{
            cout << "The Devil rolls a 1. He loses his points and now it's your turn!" << endl;
            turnScore = 0;
            change = false;
            //End turn. Breaks secondary loop.
            break;
          }

        }
      }else{

        cout << "The Devil chooses to pass. ";
        devilScore += turnScore;
        choice='p';
        turnScore = 0;
        cout << "He has " << devilScore << " points. " << endl;
        cout << "The Devil now has " << devilScore << " points." << endl;
        change = false;
        //End turn. Breaks secondary loop.
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```